# Scaling Services Horizontally

Tags: architecture, horizontal-scaling

I have a system with a service used to process scheduled tasks across a number of databases, the scheduled tasks are configured per database.  Due to the workload from an ever increasing number of databases the system needs to be scaled horizontally so that there are multiple copies of the service each installed on a separate server.   There is a common database that contains the list of databases that need to be processed.

I don’t want to statically assign a database to an instance of the service as the workload per database varies.

What I am looking for is a way to marshal the selection of the databases to process between the various instances of the services.

Suggestions please, Thanks